# Connecting to Azure SQL with PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure

i've been wrestling with connecting to azure for the last day or so.

i've gone through all the steps here https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php up to the block here:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http|https];AccountName=[yourAccount];AccountKey=[yourKey]
```

i think the namespace call prior to that isn't effective, though i'm unsure.

when i try to call the class like this

```
$tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder->getInstance()->createTableService($connectionString);
```

i get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
```

and if i change the "ServicesBuilder->" to "ServicesBuilder::" (as seen [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/table-service/#RetrieveEntity))I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ServicesBuilder' not found
```

i really just have no clue what i'm missing at this point and can't think of anything else to attempt.

any help in the right direction to just get a connection would be so greatly appreciated. one more thing to note: i'm working in codeigniter and have [this](https://github.com/thomasantony/codeigniter-azure) library included, though i've seen no use for it as of yet since i can't even connect to the db :\

thanks for any assistance-

Comment: it seems to be an issue with the `use` call, but i've not yet determined what exactly the deal is with it. i've tried dropping the `WindowsAzure` folder in several directories throughout the application still w/ no luck